# Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I've tried searching over here for this but am not finding my solution.
I have the following script:

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {
 var destArray = new Array();
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('1001').getThreads(0,1);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('Record');
          for(var m in msg){
                     destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getPlainBody());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }
Logger.log(destArray);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Rows start at "1" - this will delete the first row
sheet.deleteRow(1);
}
```

What this does is this imports the last email with the label "1001"
I have the same script for about 40 labels.
I'm trying to trigger each one every minute but i'm getting that error.
What I want to know is if there's a way to combine all "GmailApp.getUserLabelByName" requests in one request? and each result should be in a different row? 
What happens now is, it takes the result, put's it in row 2, and deletes row 1, and so on.

I don't mind having all results on one sheet.

Anyone with any idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

Could try just having 1 script loop through all your labels every hour or so if 40 every minute isn't necessary...

```
var labels = ['1001', '1002', '1003'];
for (var i in labels) {
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labels[i]).getThreads(0,1);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('Record');
          for(var m in msg){
                     destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getPlainBody());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }
}
```